# Unity - Can not change resolution

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, resolution, screen-resolution

I am having a problem with my resolution settings for a game I am making for Android. Which ever resolution I place to be rendered it always in resolution 399x639(for portrait) I tried changing in player settings, placing a custom resolution and changing it in code but does not help :( Does anyone have an idea what can be wrong?

Thanx

Comment: Any additional info or codes perhaps?

Comment: There is no special code I used. But I figured out whats the problem, at least the part of it. It seams that unity scales the game window when you hit play and does not show true resolution. And the problem with that is that my gui stuff does not scale properly. Ill just implement a object that scales everything properly and it should work fine, I hope :)

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, you can change the resolution as you said in Edit > Project Settings > Player. I think that you also know how to change it while you're developing (go to the bar above the Game View).

Well, you have to make the game to be independent of the screen resolution. For do that, you can start defining these two variables:

```
    nativeHeightResolution = 1200.0;
    scaledWidthResolution = nativeHeightResolution / Screen.height * Screen.width
```

And in the OnGUI() function you can write this:

```
    GUI.matrix = Matrix4x4.TRS (Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity, Vector3 (Screen.height / nativeHeightResolution, Screen.height / nativeHeightResolution, 1));
```

Then, if you want to draw a label, for example, you could use this:

```
    function Label_Center(pos : Vector2, text : String, style : GUIStyle) {  //draw a text label from the center of screen + position, with style
       GUI.Label(Rect (pos.x + scaledWidthResolution / 2, pos.y + nativeHeightResolution / 2, 700, 100), text, style);
    }
```

This is what I have used in my projects. I hope that it have been usefull for you.