# Resize screen and image .Android games on Unity (2d)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I want to create a 2d games on Unity (like Doodle jump) but I don't how I can resize the screen (camera and sprite) for all resolution.

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to stretch sprites dynamically depending on the resolution (width and height)

This information you can get from [Screen](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Screen.html)

Imagine you have resolution 1024x768, for these resolution you created sprite 256x128 which looks good, however if you would run it on device with higher resolution - your sprite would looks to small so you need to stretch it proportionally to the new resolution

Here is how I would solve this problem:
imagine resolution 1024x768 = 100% and 256x128 = 100%
If resolution jump to 1280x800 we need to find on how many % it did increase
lets take width for a start:
 
1024 = 100% 
1% = 1024 / 100 = 10.24 
1280 / 10.24 (or 1%) = 125%
125% - 100% = 25%
So we need to re-size our sprite width on 25%
in the same way you find % for sprite: 
256 = 100%
1% = 256 / 100 = 2.56 
2.56 (or 1%) * 25 = 64 
125% = 256 + 64 = 280 - this is new width

Repeat the same for the height, or you can find proportion for height depending on sprite size.

Note: Sprite quality might be reduced if you stretch it or shrink it too much, use vector graphic for your sprites.

Answer (score 1):

There are awesome suggestions and links in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369067/how-to-work-with-different-screen-resolutions).

Also, if you are developing 2D games on unity, I'd recommend you buying this asset called [2dtoolkit](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/908).

This costs money, but it does save a lot of time and effort. Hope this helps :)