# Converting iOS game dimensions for Unity2d android

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

I recently started working learning Unity2d from an iOS background. I am using the FWVGA Landscape (854x480) dimensions. I resized a 1136x640 background image (which I use for iOS) to 854x480 and made a sprite with the image but it only took a small portion of the screen. I had to resize the image in Unity. What are the general rules for converting dimensions from iOS to Android on Unity to get the dimensions to fit?

Comment: Do you just want to resize background image on every device?

Comment: @HamzaHasan Not only the background, I also want to resize all my image assets for android

Answer (score 1):

1136x640 is the ratio 16:9, as is 1920x1080 (1080p). Note a quick way to check the ratio: 16/9 = 1.77r. 1920/1080 = 1.77r. 1136/640=1.77r, 854/480 = 1.77r. All the same 16:9 ratio.

So, for Android phones that are also 16:9 you don't "need" to resize your assets unless say you want to up the resolution for quality sake on more powerful Android devices.

If you want to do it quick and easy then you want to draw your game in a camera at 1336x640 and then scale the camera view to match the resolution of the device you are running on (be it 1920x1080, 640x480, etc - all the same ratio).

You get problems with devices that are not 16:9 like tablets or phones that are say 16:10, 5:3, 3:2, or the iPads and Nexus 9 tablets at 4:3. This is a long subject though and there are lots of guides around to help. Try searching for "Unity 2d multiple screen ratios".

Answer (score 0):

I think there are just too many variables to make this work "simply"

854x480 doesn't sound like a 'standard' HxW to me. and Unity is a 3D game engine which means its camera is on the Z axis when you are "looking down upon" a 2D game.

So the camera Z axis(Which apparently Unity tries to 'adjust' to match the phone's size, the phone's physical size, the size of the image you are using, etc. There are just a lot of variables. I would recommend https://stackoverflow.com/a/21375938 to see if that helps.