# How to make sure UI layout fits every individual supported device in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, user-interface, mobile

I published an app on the Play Store, I developed in Unity, but some of my friends showed me the UI layout looks a bit different than what I expected and saw on my testing device.

Is there a way to enforce every supported device to display my game and layout exactly as I expect?

I know that in Android Studio, there is the wrap content and constraint (Or whatever it called), but I am not aware of such options in Unity.

P.S
It is important to bear in mind that I have a scene with AR Camera (Not a regular one), while the other is a regular camera.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to Work With Different Screen Resolutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21369067/how-to-work-with-different-screen-resolutions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's new tool in Unity called `Device Simulator`

Here's a good tutorial: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PLQ4ywB13eg)

But the main fix can be done just in Canvas -> Canvas Scaler. UI Scale Mode set to `Scale With Screen Size` then set Match to 0 if game is vertical or 1 if game is landscape. Then set anchors to borders for UI elements.

Comment: Thank you! It seems like I can only write numbers in the UI objects anchors, and not set them to borders.

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.ugui@1.0/manual/UIBasicLayout.html#anchor-presets